# How to rewrite video urls from /feed that have autoplay enabled

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, strtr

I ran into an interesting Issue today working on a Wall Feed Plugin.  A majority of videos posted to the feed via youtube have autoplay enabled.

```
"source": "http://www.youtube.com/v/IXTS79iDTNA?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1",
```

I am trying to rewrite that url before embeding using php.  How would you do this?

So far i have tried using strtr(); with array, seems though if there are alot of videos in the feed, things seem to slow down alot.

---

```
    /* $fvalue[source] is the video url in graph api */ 
    if($fvalue[source]){
            $reWrite = array("autoplay=1" => "autoplay=0");
        $getEmbed = $fvalue[source];
        $strAuto = strtr($getEmbed, $reWrite);
        echo '<object><embed src="'.$strAuto.'"></embed></object>';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is slow because of the `strstr`. Roughly speaking, `str_replace` is 30-50 times faster.

```
//This code should be at least 30 times faster.
if($fvalue[source]){
    $strAuto = str_replace("autoplay=1", "autoplay=0", $fvalue[source]);
    echo '<object><embed src="'.$strAuto.'"></embed></object>';
}
```

Comment: This took about 900ms off the render time thank you.  Reward goes to you but i can not reward you for 1 more hour.

Comment: mm, 900ms is also big number in terms of user-experience. Then maybe is it better to do this process off-line and cache it.

Comment: Doing offline is not an option unfortunately, since the plugin pulls this information live from graph each time.  Benchmarks how ever did showed no improvement in performance when i added the full array, including all flash objects from all sources known to use the auto-play features, including music.  I am looking into using preg_replace() since i am not using regular expression.  If you have any knowledge of this use i would appreciate any insight.

Comment: here is a sample of the plugin https://shawnsspace.com/plugins/TimeLineFeed.php?pageid=StuffJustForFun&since=900+days+ago&until=now&limit=16&type=posts&fh=750  loading a page with alot of videos.  All have auto play enabled.  Avg is 2000ms with both strtr, and str_replace.

Comment: preg_replace is slower than str_replace. Check this fo more info http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=175031.0

If you can send me your full or sample file, I will benchmark it using xhprof, and give you better alternatives solutions.

Comment: if the feeds are pulled in realtime. what about generating those feeds each 1 min using cron, and let this plugin reads them from file system ?
then even to make things faster, cache the result of opening the feeds file in apc so that it will not be opened with each request.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4933/discussion-between-laith-shadeed-and-shawn-e-carter)